# Identifying the transitive match records in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Scenario1 :-

Indirectly the rowid object 3 and 4 which belongs to the same source A is coming together.

```
 Rowid_object   Rowid_object_source Rowid_object_matched    Rowid_object_matched_Source
    2                       X              3                            A 
    2                       X              4                            A
    1                       Y              2                            X
```

we need to identify these kind of  records and delete one

Scenario 2 :-

Indirectly the rowid_object 2 and 4  which belongs to same source A is coming together.

```
 Rowid_object   Rowid_object_source Rowid_object_matched    Rowid_object_matched_Source
     1               X                  2                              A
     2               A                  3                              Y
     3               Y                  1                              X
     4               A                  3                              Y
```

we need to identify these kind of  records and delete one

I have tried using connect_by prior but i could not get it . Kindly let me know how we can achieve this using Oracle SQL.

Comment: I have tried this sql                                                                                                                            SELECT ROWID_OBJECT_MATCHED  "ROWID_OBJECT_MATCHED", CONNECT_BY_ROOT ROWID_OBJECT_MATCHED "ROWID_OBJECT",
   LEVEL-1 "Pathlen", SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ROWID_OBJECT_MATCHED, '/') "Path"
   FROM table
   WHERE LEVEL > 1 and rowid_object_matched = 'value' and trunc(create_date) = trunc(sysdate)
   CONNECT BY NOCYCLE prior rowid_object_matched = rowid_object

Answer (score 0):

In the below example, sourcetable is just setting up the data as in your first example. In BSET we add the column keep_only_1 which is a counter of like records. As the final step we only keep the record where keep_only_1 = 1. I leave it to you to use this method to solve your second question. Because this is entirely self contained, you can copy and paste it into SQL*Plus to see the results.

```
WITH
sourcetable AS
    (SELECT 2       AS rowid_object
          , 'X'     AS rowid_object_source
          , 3       AS rowid_object_matched
          , 'A'     AS rowid_object_matched_source
       FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 2, 'X', 4, 'A' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1, 'Y', 2, 'X' FROM DUAL),
bset AS
    (SELECT rowid_object
          , rowid_object_source
          , rowid_object_matched
          , rowid_object_matched_source
          , ROW_NUMBER( )
                OVER( PARTITION BY rowid_object
                                 , rowid_object_source
                                 , rowid_object_matched_source
                      ORDER BY rowid_object_matched )    AS keep_only_1
       FROM sourcetable)
SELECT rowid_object
 , rowid_object_source
 , rowid_object_matched
 , rowid_object_matched_source
 FROM bset
 WHERE keep_only_1 = 1;
```

Comment: Have tried with Multiple scenario's , I can see this SQL is giving my the records based on the rownumber partition. In certain ways it is picking the other scenario Say        Rowid_object  Rowid_object_source  Rowid_object_matched rowid_object_matched_source
1 B 3 A
2 C 3 A